# Does jQuery work well with Polymer 2?

Tags: jquery, polymer-2.x

There are many mixed answers. But they're all answers from a few years ago and relating to Polymer 1.

Thanks.

Comment: If you only want a query-like selecting of DOM nodes, you can use document.querySelector

Comment: jQuery should turn deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work but it won´t work well. Have a look [this](https://medium.com/dev-channel/dont-use-jquery-plugins-with-shadow-dom-e161f1891511). The only way jquery and polymer work well togehter is polymer 1 and shady dom but thats deprecated.

Comment: As Pascal mentioned it wont work well and I wouldn't risk it as I spend countless hours trying to fix issues that I encountered when using JQuery with Polymer. Just recently Rob Dodson published an article about it.

http://robdodson.me/dont-use-jquery-with-shadow-dom/

Answer (score 0):

The question can be interpreted in two ways - can legacy jquery code create polymer components/custom tags?

The answer is **YES**.

The other interpretation is - can I use jquery INSIDE my web components?

The answer is **"maybe, but its a really bad idea, don't do it"**.