# Should I use JQuery with my Polymer 2.0 application?

Tags: jquery, polymer-2.x

Should I use JQuery in my polymer 2.0 application, I precisely have a requirement to use JQuery table inside my polymer component, I am wondering if this is agood idea to combine them both?

Comment: The going wisdom seems no. Answered here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346250/1316011) with link to here (http://robdodson.me/dont-use-jquery-with-shadow-dom/).

Answer (score 1):

Definitly not a good Idea. At least with Polymer 2 it won´t work really well with shadow Dom. Maybe Jquery will fix this at some point in the future. If you must use Jquery you can use Polymer 1 with shady dom then it will work just fine.